# how to use ajax in cscart

Tags: php, ajax, cs-cart

```
<script>
function showHint(str) {

    if (str.length == 0) {
        document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = "";
        return;
    } else {
        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = this.responseText;
            }
        }
        xmlhttp.open("GET", "index.php?dispatch=paysrk.paymod?amount="+str, true);
        alert(+str);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
}
</script>
```

i think problem is here.**Amount** is not geting .url is not working.

*index.php?dispatch=paysrk.paymod?amount*

**Question updates:-**
[image]

My requirements:

When i click the unsubscribe button status in the database change to "US" and change UNSUBSCRIBE button to SUBSCRIBE. A notification with unsubscription completed

Comment: what's your str output?

Comment: it's just a value from the textbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your request is done from CS-Cart environment please try:

```
<script>
function showHint(str){
    if (str.length == 0) {
        document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = "";
        return;
    } else {
        $.ceAjax('request', fn_url('paysrk.paymod'), {
            method: 'get',
            caching: false,
            hidden:true,
            data: { 'amount': str },
            callback: function(data){
                alert(data);
            }
        });
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: can you tell me more about using ajax in cs cart.

Comment: you can return values to ajax callback from php with Tygh::$app['ajax']->assign('x', $x); please let me know what do you need to know?

Comment: i just edited the question. Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 1):

i think your problem is in the url syntax.

the first parameter to pass to the `url` is after `?` and all the other parameters should preceded with `&`
so your `GET` `url` should be like this

```
index.php?dispatch=paysrk.paymod&amount

xmlhttp.open("GET", "index.php?dispatch=paysrk.paymod&amount="+str, true);
```

Answer (score 1):

you do exactly like this.
    
    function showHint(str) {

```
    if (str.length == 0) {
        document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = "";
        return;
    } else {
        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = this.responseText;
            }
        }
        xmlhttp.open("GET", "index.php?dispatch=paysrk.paymod?amount="+str, true));
        alert(+str);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
}
</script>
```